# Angular HttpClient mapping removes getters from target object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using HttpClient to get Json from the API and using the autoMapping of that HttpClient to map the json to the target object like this:

```
this.httpClient.post<Person>(url, body, { headers: headers, params: httpParams }).retry(ConfigurationService.apiHttpRetries)
```

My problem is that my Person class contains getters like:

```
get FullName() { return `${this.firstName} + ' ' ${this.lastName}`; }
```

after httpClient.Post, i am getting a Person object that contains only the fields  that returned from the json and not other properties and without my FullName getter.

I tried to use Object.Assign but it also not working...

What is the big deal of the httpClient.post generic method if its not doing map and only doing something like return JSON.parse(jsonResult)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.assign()` within the class constructor:

```
 class Person {
     firstName: string;
     lastName: string;;
         constructor(data: Object|Person) {
            Object.assign(this,data);
         }
      get FullName() { return `${this.firstName} + ' ' ${this.lastName}`; }
    }

    ...

        this.httpClient.post<Person>(url, body, headers).pipe(
              retry(ConfigurationService.apiHttpRetries),
              map(personProperties => new Person(personProperties),
       );
```

Don't need to map each property youself:

```
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
```

Comment: i will check that, could you explain why it didn't work when the Object.assign is outside, like in my example on the above comment?

Comment: Yerkon - Could you please answer my comment?

Comment: Maybe something with your `result`

Comment: Yerkon - What should work? So i don't need to use the constructor trick?

Comment: you right, I updated the question, my result is an array httpClient.post<Person[]> and not httpClient.post<Person>... Can you advice?

Answer (score 5):

The generic argument is only used for typing at compile time. You are *informing* the rest of your code that the object returned from the response will be compatible with `Person`. If the response doesn't include `firstName` or `lastName` properties your code still will not work properly unless you check the object shape yourself. If you want that object to have methods or other getters you will have to instantiate it yourself.

```
interface PersonResponse {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

this.httpClient.post<Person>(url, body, headers).pipe(
  retry(ConfigurationService.apiHttpRetries),
  map(personProperties => new Person(personProperties),
);
```

So you can have

```
class Person {
  constructor({ firstName, lastName }) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  get FullName() { return `${this.firstName} + ' ' ${this.lastName}`; }
}
```

Comment: Is there an option instead of defined in the constructor all the fields of the class?, i am looking for something more generic...

Btw, why  .map((result) => {
          return  Object.assign(new type(), result);
        } is not doing the trick?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working / not doing the trick? That seems to be an okay way to do it to me

Comment: Pils -  Object.assign(new type(), result); also doesn't keep the other properties and getters.